# Spring MVC and JFreeChart (Displaying charts in views)

Tags: spring-mvc, jfreechart

In my Spring web MVC application, I'm planing to display some JFree charts on my jsp views, I'm not sure how to do this, 
since the first idea i had didn't work for me, generating an image, then retrieving it from the folder.

Now I think, are Controllers able to retrun images directly ?
suppose that's my service interface:

```
public interface ReportingService {
    Image getChart() ;
}
```

Can I do something like this, and how can I call this image from my jsp ?

```
@Controller
public class ReportingController {
    @Autowired
    private ReportingService reportingService ;

    @RequestMapping("/reports")
    public Image handleReports(){
         return reportingService.getChart() ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
@RequestMapping("/reports")    
public void handleReports(HttpServletResponse response){    
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");    
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();   
    writeChartAsJPEG(out , reportingService.getChart() , 400, 400);    
}
```

Now,  form in your jsp page `<img src="/reports" />`

It will create and present the chart on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Jfreechart extensively in my project. I used CEWOLF framework to put them in JSP.
http://cewolf.sourceforge.net/new/index.html This is open source framework which provides direct JSP tags to put chart in page

If you have many charts to work with, its worth to use this framework.
For your query, as far as I remeber, Image that you are referring must be JFreechart image and not java applet image. you will have to convert it using byte stream conversion.

Comment: cewolf is interesting, I just need an example of how using it in spring MVC based application.